# How to prove that function f is a surjection?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

How would you prove that this function is a surjection? I know how to explain it but I need to somehow prove it mathematically

$f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})×\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus\{\emptyset\}$

$f(\mathrm{X},n)=\mathrm{X}\cup\{n\}$

Comment: Take an arbitrary thing in the target. Find something in the domain that is mapped to it. You'll struggle, in this case, because it's not true.

Comment: Indeed, an image element is the empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to attempt to prove this is say.  Let $A \in P(\mathbb N)$ be an arbitrary subject.  Then try to find a solution for $B$ and $n$ so that

$f(B,n) = B\cup \{n\} = A$.

Then that requires that $n$ must be an element of $A$.  Any element of $A$ can do but we must realize that $A$ must have elements in the first place.  If $A = \emptyset$ there is no $n\in A$ and $n \in B\cup \{n\} = f(B,n) \not \subset A = \emptyset$ for any set $B$ and any element $n$...

So $f$ is not onto as $f(B,n) = \emptyset$ has no solution.

However if we consider $g:P(\mathbb N) \times N \to P(\mathbb N)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ via $g(X,n) = X \cup \{n\}$ we can attempt to solve for any $A \subset \mathbb N$ where $A \ne \emptyset$,  $g(B, n) = A$.

For $g(B, n) = B \cup \{n\} = A \ne \emptyset$ then we must have $n \in A$.  $n$ may be *any* element and we must have $A\setminus\{n\}\setminus B\subset A\setminus\{n\}$.

So $g(A, n) = A \cup \{n\} = A$ or $g(A\setminus \{n\},n) = (A\setminus \{n\},n)\cup \{n\} = A.$  For *any* $n \in A$ for any nonempty subset of $\mathbb N$.

So $g$ *is* onto.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})×\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ defined as above is
not surjective as empty set has no pre-image in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})×\mathbb{N}$.

**Edit:** Since you have changed your question,you can do as follows. Take any $Y \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus \emptyset$. Clearly $Y$ is the union of countably many singleton sets of the form $\{n\}$. Choose any $n_0\in Y$ and let  $X=Y\setminus \{n_0\}$. Then  $f(X,n_0)=Y$.

Comment: And, what happens if $Y=\emptyset$?

Comment: @ThomasShelby Yes, it is not possible.

Comment: @Gödel Thank you. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Jimmy The question is about an element $X\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\times\mathbb{N}$ such tht $f(X)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Gödel Do you mean  $f(X,n)$?

Comment: Not. note that I take $X\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\times\mathbb{N}$

Comment: You're right, it's not a surjection! Thank you, I didn't consider the empty set, I'll edit the post so that it makes sense